# How to save xml file after reverse some childs on it

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml, xdoc

I have an xml file and I want to reverse some nodes and after that I want to save the result.
I used XDocumnt and use revese function on it and it reversed correctly but after that I don not know how to save the file.
the original file like the follwing

```
    <root>
  <parent>
    <child>
      <sec>
        <p>
          <my-formula>
            <test id="H1"></test id="H1">
          </my-formula>
          <my-formula>
            <test id="H2"></test id="H2">
          </my-formula>
          <my-formula>
            <test id="H3"></test id="H3">
          </my-formula>
        </p>
      </sec>
      <sec>
        <p>
          <my-formula>
            <test id="H4"></test id="H4">
          </my-formula>
          <my-formula>
            <test id="H5"></test id="H5">
          </my-formula>
          <my-formula>
            <test id="H6"></test id="H6">
          </my-formula>
        </p>
      </sec>
    </child>
  </parent>
</root>
```

I need to reverse it as the following:

```
    <root>
  <parent>
    <child>
      <sec>
        <p>
          <my-formula>
            <test id="H6"></test id="H6">
          </my-formula>
          <my-formula>
            <test id="H5"></test id="H5">
          </my-formula>
          <my-formula>
            <test id="H4"></test id="H4">
          </my-formula>
        </p>
      </sec>
      <sec>
        <p>
          <my-formula>
            <test id="H3"></test id="H3">
          </my-formula>
          <my-formula>
            <test id="H2"></test id="H2">
          </my-formula>
          <my-formula>
            <test id="H1"></test id="H1">
          </my-formula>
        </p>
      </sec>
    </child>
  </parent>
</root>
```

After that I want to save it into new file.

> can any one help me?

Comment: How does the input xml looks like and how should the result xml look like?

Comment: After reverse it be OK, but after save I get the old value

Comment: I need to save the result after I reversed it

Comment: Update your question and add examples how it looks like and how you want the result will look like

Comment: Also note: Reverse method RETURNS descendants in reverse order.

Comment: then I should replace that descendant and then save, 
Is not it؟

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find that I should use `ReplaceNode` function to replace reversed nodes then save the file 
but reverse function not reverse the nodes inside the file, no it just return the new reversed values and I should replace them manually as the following

```
var fileDataXDoc = XDocument.Load("filePath");
                    var elems = fileDataXDoc.Descendants("node_to_be_reversed").Reverse();

                    int counter = 0;

                    foreach (var xElement in elems)
                    {
                        fileDataXDoc.Descendants("node_to_be_reversed).ElementAt(counter).ReplaceNodes(xElement.Nodes());
                        counter ++;
                    }

                    fileDataXDoc.Save("newReversedFile.xml");
```